# Should every open set of a zero-dimensional topology be closed set?

Tags: general-topology

zero dimensional topology: A topological space having a base of sets that are at the same time open and closed in it.(https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Zero-dimensional_space)

Should every open set of a zero-dimensional topology be closed set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For instance, $\Bbb Q$ with the usual topology is zero-dimensional, but $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ is an open set that is not closed: $0$ is in its closure.

More generally, let $X$ be any zero-dimensional $T_1$ space whose topology is not the discrete topology, and let $x$ be any non-isolated point of $X$; then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is an open set that is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of a point in the Cantor set is open, but not closed.